# role based security in CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2016

I created a new role called `medical administrators`

My motive is to allow the user role to create/edit/delete the medical records

I went to the custom entities tab and selected "Create, Read, write, Delete, append, append to" against the custom entity.

But when the user tries to access the CRM environment they get the below message

> Insufficient Permissions
>
> You do not have permission to access these records. Contact your
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM administrator.

What else should I add for the particular user group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provided `create,read,write,delete` to entities like contacts, notes etc and it started working

It is because, there are look up fields to contacts in the entity form of the medical case

Also in the customizations section give read access for **Process** and the below fields

[image]

Comment: lookup fields require Append/Append To permissions, depending on which side of the relationship you are on.  You likely only needed to give the minimum permissions for the user to view whatever records are on the homepage, and since the user didn't have that access, they probably got the message right when they logged in.